# Authorization Header Or RequiresAuthentication Attribute

Tags: c#, rest, openrasta

I am using OpenRasta for building my REST API and want to enable the Authentication for selected number of methods in Handler. So i have put **RequiresAuthentication attribute** for those methods.

I have a authentication scheme defined for it. So when i specify **Authorization Header** in HTTP Request it should check for authentication. In ideal scenario, it should not check for authentication for the methods which don't have **RequiresAuthentication attribute** specified. But instead of that it checks for authentication as i have specified **Authorization Header** for the request.

Is it a acceptable behavior or it should check if the attribute is assigned to the method and check for authentication even if the Authorization Header is specified ?

If OpenRasta checks for Authorization Header what is the use of **RequiresAuthentication attribute** ?